# How to handle a model with a lot of drop down lists in Asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a model with a LOT of foreign keys.  Right now, I'm populating view data:

```
ViewData["fieldname"]=new selectlist(entityframeworkmodel.foreigntable.ToList(),"fieldkey","valuefield");
```

I really don't like this approach.  For one thing, I'm supposed to just name the field the same thing and trust that it will get stored in the model.  I don't really understand how that works but it's a little worrisome.

Secondly, my code is now a bit of a mess.

```
 //Address drop downs
 ViewData["AddressType"] = new SelectList(ent.tblAddressTypes.ToList(), "AddressID", "AddressType");

        //Contact Drop Downs
        ViewData["ContactTitle"] = new SelectList(ent.tblContactTitles.ToList(), "ContactTitleID", "Title");

        //Event
        ViewData["EventStatus"] = new SelectList(ent.tblEventStatus.ToList(), "EventStatusID", "EventStatus");
        ViewData["EventType"] = new SelectList(ent.tblEventTypes.ToList(), "EventTypeID", "EventType");
        ViewData["Frequency"] = new SelectList(ent.tblFrequencies.ToList(), "FrequencyID", "Frequency");
        ViewData["cLanguage"] = new SelectList(ent.tblLanguages.ToList(), "LanguageID", "Language");
        ViewData["PrimaryAgeGroup"] = new SelectList(ent.tblAgeGroupSet.ToList(), "AgeGroupID", "AgeGroup");
        ViewData["PrimaryEntity"] = new SelectList(ent.tblEntities.ToList(), "EntityID", "Entity");
        ViewData["PrimaryEthnicGroup"] = new SelectList(ent.tblEthnicTargets.ToList(), "EthnicTargetID", "EthnicTarget");
        ViewData["PrimaryLanguage"] = new SelectList(ent.tblLanguages.ToList(), "LanguageID", "Language");
        ViewData["TargetGroup"] = new SelectList(ent.tblTargetGroups.ToList(), "TargetGroupID", "TargetGroup");
        ViewData["TargetFocus"] = new SelectList(ent.tblTargetGroups.ToList(), "TargetGroupID", "TargetGroup");
        ViewData["PrimaryUserGroup"] = new SelectList(ent.tblUserGroups.ToList(), "UserGroupID", "UserGroup");
        ViewData["PrimaryTargetGroup"] = new SelectList(ent.tblTargetGroups.ToList(), "TargetGroupID", "TargetGroup");
        ViewData["OS"] = new SelectList(ent.tblOutreachSpecialists.ToList(), "OSID", "LastName");'
```

The other issue is I don't see how I can test this.  I've written a repository method that just maps the id values from the drop downs into the respective EF objects.

How are other people dealing with this?  I do set up these drop downs in a few places, so I thought about putting them in a controller method.

Thoughts?

P.S. Kind of thinking about this: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/06/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-3-passing-viewdata-from-controllers-to-views.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Drop down lists in MVC can be painful if you are *determined* to stick with "pure" practices and architecure. For my own sanity, I am tending to lean to the following technique as described by the respected Mike Hadlow: [Populating Drop Down Lists in ASP.NET MVC](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2010/10/populating-drop-down-lists-in-aspnet.html).

This method *does* violate data access from the view ... but its implemented in a clean way that I am persoanaly finding quite acceptable for the ease of use this offers.